# Check if terms are in columns and remove

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, filter

Originally I wanted to filter only for specific terms, however I've found python will match the pattern regardless of specificity eg:

```
possibilities = ['temp', 'degc']
temp = (df.filter(regex='|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in temp_possibilities))
                  .columns.to_list())
```

Output does find the correct columns, but unfortunately it also returns columns like temp_uncalibrated, which I do not want.

So to solve this, so far I define and remove unwanted columns first, before filtering ie:

```
    if 'temp_uncalibrated' in df.columns:
        df = df.drop('temp_uncalibrated',axis = 1)
    else:
        pass
```

However, I have found more and more of these unwanted columns, and now the code looks messy and hard to read with all the terms. Is there a way to do this more succinctly? I tries putting the terms in a list and do it that way, but it does not work, ie:

```
    if list in df.columns:
        df = df.drop(list,axis = 1)
    else:
        pass
```

I thought maybe a def function might be a better way to do it, but not really sure where to start.

Comment: can you provide an explicit example list of column names to match and not to match?

Comment: you can drop multiple columns by passing them to the drop function. Maybe you can split in 3 steps? 1) `col_to_match = ['a', 'b', ...]` 2) `matched_columns = [col_name if col_name in df.columns  for col_name in col_to_match]` 3) `df.drop(matched_columns, axis=1)` something like this?

Comment: you can probably directly select the correct columns, but the logic is currently ambiguous

Comment: Sure! So for example in my code it cycles through thousands of files, reading them in and creating a dataframe, but there's not consistancy with column headers, hence the filtering to pull out if that particular dataframe has a column I want to pull out (eg all ways of saying calibrated temperature) but I want to avoid columns with similar name that are incorrect (eg all ways of saying uncalibrated temperature). So: desired would be eg 'temp' , 'temperature' , 'degc', 'tmp', and undesired would be the same but with uncalibrated or uncal or uncalib in front, in any combination

Comment: can you provide explicit examples?

Comment: Yes so desired:  temp_poss = ['temp','temperature', 'degc', 'tmp']                       example dataframe columns:   'index', 'temp', 'temp_uncalib', 'other_variables'                  In this example, I would want to filter for 'temp'  but avoid 'temp_uncalib'. My current way takes both, as the string pattern 'temp' appears in both.